# All systemd states

Tags: linux, systemd

systemd's state is composed of 3 subcomponents (LOAD, ACTIVE, SUB); what are the different values that these subcomponents can take? I know LOAD can be "loaded", ACTIVE can be "failed", and SUB can be "failed", but what are the others?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### what are the others?

The first source, [systemd, init — systemd system and service manager](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.html)
lists:

- active
- inactive
- activating
- deactivating
- failed

The second source, [About System-State Targets](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52668_01/E54669/html/ol7-sysdtargets.html) lists (in addition):

- not-found
- dead

---

#### systemd, init — systemd system and service manager

> **Concepts**
>
> systemd provides a dependency system between various entities called
>   "units" of 12 different types. Units encapsulate various objects that
>   are relevant for system boot-up and maintenance. The majority of units
>   are configured in unit configuration files, whose syntax and basic set
>   of options is described in systemd.unit(5), however some are created
>   automatically from other configuration, dynamically from system state
>   or programmatically at runtime.
>
> Units may be "**active**" (meaning started, bound, plugged in, ...,
>   depending on the unit type, see below), or "**inactive**" (meaning
>   stopped, unbound, unplugged, ...), as well as in the process of being
>   activated or deactivated, i.e. between the two states (these states
>   are called "**activating**", "**deactivating**"). A special
>   "**failed**" state is available as well, which is very similar to
>   "inactive" and is entered when the service failed in some way (process
>   returned error code on exit, or crashed, or an operation timed out).
>   If this state is entered, the cause will be logged, for later
>   reference.
>
> **Note that the various unit types may have a number of additional substates, which are mapped to the five generalized unit states
>   described here.**

Source [systemd, init — systemd system and service manager](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.html)

---

#### About System-State Targets

Contains example output including the following values:

> - LOAD "loaded" or "not-found"
> - ACTIVE "active" or "inactive"
> - SUB "active" or "dead"

Source [About System-State Targets](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52668_01/E54669/html/ol7-sysdtargets.html)

Comment: "I have no idea if this list is complete" - Seems strange to me that this information is so hard to find :)

Comment: The values are probably defined somewhere in the Unix source code, but I wouldn't know where to look.

Comment: It's not actually hard to find.  David Postill is quoting _the manual page_, accessible with `man systemd`.

Comment: yes, last part is incomplete.  Looking at `systemctl list-units --all`, processes can be in state (SUB) `exited`, sockets `listening`, timers `waiting`.

Comment: Note "System-State Targets" is not a relevant topic, it just happened to illustrate some of the state types.  To see all possible states, run `systemctl --state=help`.

Comment: How can a service go from `Failed` to `active` state?

Comment: @MUYBelgium I've no idea - perhaps by fixing the problem and restarting the service?